# How to insert custom control into Office Word document

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, office-addins

I want to insert my custom control into the currently opened Word document using VSTO. I have an application which communicates with my already existing VSTO Word plugin over COM. So far i have been using a workaround where i inserted pictures of my custom control as a InlineShape (as images) into the document. This was fine for now, since Word was automatically saving it inside the document, took care of resizing, deleting with the delete key, drag droping image as a singe character and so on... But now i am encountering some problems regarding adding new functionalities (eg. Right click on control (image) click). Now i am looking for an alternatives, how to insert custom control (probably an ActiveX control?) .
I have created an example when i insert a custom control with the Microsoft.Office.Tools.Word.Document.Controls.AddControl() function, but here are some problems:

- The control can not be dragged around the range of the document
- The control is not saved when the document is closed and reopened
- Control does not work when the document zoom is not 100%

See the picture below:

[image]

I have also noticed, that i can insert an object into the current word document (insert -> object -> eg. Microsoft Word Document, see picture below)

[image]

This inserted object has all the functionality which i need (drag-drop as a single character, saving on document close, resize, functionality when document zoom is not 100%,...) This is exactly what i want to achieve, but instead of another Microsoft Word object, I would like to display my custom control. See the picture below for comparison between MS Word Document object and my custom control inside opened document:
[image]

Now i have already spent quite some time googling and doing the research but i am running out of ideas on how to successfully create this to work... If anyone is familiar with the solution of could provide any details on it, it would be extremelly helpful! I have also tried doing something with the new plugins Office add-ins, but keep in mind that i am developing a Windows app, i do not need crossplatform functionality and Word plugin needs to be accessible from the other app (just like current solution, where i access it using COM). Hopefully the explanation was clear enough, i am more than ready to provide additional information if needed!

Comment: Although this appears to be a programming question, you do not share your existing code. If you want help with how Word works, a more appropriate forum would be the Super User (https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-word), Word Answers (http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word), or the Word Forum (http://www.msofficeforums.com/word/). Please only post in one, though. --- Look into Content Controls (which are not ActiveX).

Comment: Thank you for the links! I will post my question there!

Comment: Cross-posted at https://www.msofficeforums.com/word/46725-how-insert-custom-control-into-office-word.html  This question may be closed.