# Is there a way to select a custom control (to enable move and resize) that was programatically added to an Office document?

Tags: c#, excel, winforms, vsto, office-addins

**Background**: following the [MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/adding-controls-to-office-documents-at-run-time?view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp), I am programmatically adding a control to an Excel spreadsheet like so:

```
ControlSite controlSite = vstoWorksheet.Controls.AddControl(webViewControl, 100, 100, 400, 300, "webView");
```

**Goal**: to allow the user to resize and move the custom control the way other items embeddable in Excel spreadsheets are. Here is an empty chart for example:

[image: selected, empty chart]

This chart has been "selected" by clicking on it. From here it can be resized by dragging the circles and moved by dragging on the border or within the chart.

This chart was programmatically added as well:

```
Chart chart = vstoWorksheet.Controls.AddChart(30, 30, 300, 200, "chart");
```

**Problem**: clicking on the custom control does not select it in the same way (the border and circles don't appear, and you can't press the `delete` key to delete it).

**What I've tried**: Since I couldn't find anything online about this, I was pretty deep into a re-implementation but struggling with edge cases (as expected). Randomly I came across the [ControlSite.Select](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.tools.excel.controlsite.select?view=vsto-2017) method and decided to try it out. I wired it into a mouse click event handler I was surprised to see that, after clicking on my control and then clicking out of Excel, it yielded the border + circles UI and allowed me to move and resize exactly how I wanted.

```
private void onGotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _controlSite.Select(false); // I've also tried true, and a bunch of other things like different event handlers, programmatically changing focus after, etc.
}
```

Is there a better/supported way to access this functionality? It's currently unreliable since it requires some odd focus jumping around, and also listening to the winforms/WPF click events. It seems like since this functionality is available, there must be a much more sensible way to use it.

Additional notes: after `Select` is called, and without doing the "lose focus trick", the function bar in excel is populated as indicated in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-add-windows-forms-controls-to-office-documents?view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp). The control is deletable with the delete key at this time. However, the border + ellipses do not appear.

[image: excel function bar, populated]

Comment: This is the closest question I could find to what I was asking, but it's been migrated repeatedly and apparently never answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66871824/how-to-insert-custom-control-into-office-word-document

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding a web browser instance to the document, you may consider placing it on the custom task pane in Excel. In that case you will a better control on how it is resized. Read more about that in the [How to: Add a custom task pane to an application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-add-a-custom-task-pane-to-an-application?view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp) article.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion; unfortunately, it is a requirement to have it embedded in the document.